# MySQL exec time black magic

Tags: mysql, select, join, where-clause

So my mysql query's been loading for 25sec every time. I split query and found out that it works perfectly without one of WHERE conditions. Condition causing problem is :

```
eshop_products.id IN 
(SELECT product-id 
   FROM eshop_productCombinations 
   WHERE eshop_productCombinations.recomended = 1 
   GROUP BY product-id)
```

Without this condition query took 0.019 sec to load. BUT when I execute this select separately, it takes only 0.026 sec to load:

```
SELECT product-id 
FROM eshop_productCombinations 
WHERE eshop_productCombinations.recomended = 1 
GROUP BY product-id
```

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong with my main query? Thank you.

Here's full query (although I don't think it'd be useful for anybody):

```
SELECT
CAST(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      price_with_vat ORDER BY IF(eshop_products_cache.`stock` > 0, 1, 0) DESC,
      IF(
        eshop_products.`type_default_price`=2,eshop_products_cache.`price_with_vat`,
        if(
          eshop_products.`type_default_price`=0,eshop_products_cache.`default`,null
          )
      ) DESC,
      IF(eshop_products.`type_default_price`=1,eshop_products_cache.`price`, null) ASC
    ),
    ",
    ",
    1
  ) AS DECIMAL(10,2)
) AS `price_with_vat`,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    eshop_products_cache.combination_id ORDER BY IF(eshop_products_cache.`stock` > 0, 1, 0) DESC,
    IF(
      eshop_products.`type_default_price`=2,
      eshop_products_cache.`price_with_vat`,
      if(
        eshop_products.`type_default_price`=0,
        eshop_products_cache.`default`,
        null
      )
    ) DESC,
    IF(eshop_products.`type_default_price`=1,eshop_products_cache.`price`, null)
    ASC
  ),
  ",
  ",
  1
) AS `combination_id`,
if( eshop_products.id in ('5993', '6144', '6663', '5120', '5376', '5632', '5888', '6400', '6656', '5121', '5377', '5633'), 1, 0) AS new
FROM `eshop_products` LEFT JOIN `eshop_products_cache` ON eshop_products_cache.product_id=eshop_products.`id` WHERE
(
  (
    (
      eshop_products.stockType = 2 AND eshop_products_cache.stock > 0
    )
    OR eshop_products.stockType <> 2
  )
)
AND
(
  price_with_vat > 0
)
AND
(
  eshop_products.recomended = 1
  OR
  eshop_products.id IN (
    SELECT `product-id` FROM eshop_productCombinations WHERE eshop_productCombinations.recomended = 1 GROUP BY `product-id`
  )
)
AND
(
  eshop_products.active = '1'
)
AND (dateStartPublish <= NOW() OR dateStartPublish IS NULL)
AND (dateStopPublish >= NOW() OR dateStopPublish IS NULL)
GROUP BY `eshop_products`.`id`, `eshop_products_cache`.`product_id` ORDER BY RAND() ASC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: not trying to sound sarcastic but it's this part `eshop_products.id IN 
(SELECT product-id FROM eshop_productCombinations 
WHERE eshop_productCombinations.recomended = 1 GROUP BY product-id)`

Comment: Did you perhaps intend to ask how this can be speeded up? Then post your explain output and provide some information about your tables, preferably the show create table.

Comment: I guess I'm really dumb, I dont see where's the problem

Comment: but you just said it works perfectly with out it1

Comment: Well, yes, it usually executes in 1-3 secs on other sites, but this time it needs 20+ seconds for some reasons

Comment: Yes, it works without it. And yes, I guess problem IS in this line, but I need this where check and it executes really fast outside of this query

Comment: Try running your slow query with `EXPLAIN` added. See if that gives you any clues

Comment: It's called a dependent subquery. They are pretty much inherently expensive in terms of performance, because the subquery has to run for each potential match, so even if the main query (without the subquery) returns 1000 rows, you are running that subquery 1000 times (once for each match). Check out:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html

Comment: This means even if your main query taker .1 second and your subquery, when run directly and by itself takes .25 seconds, if the main query returns 1000 rows, it takes 1000 * .25 seconds to run that dependant subquery. Now the two separate queries that both only take .35 seconds total when run separately will take ~250 seconds.

Comment: @Anthony Thank you very much! It solved my problem! I posted correct answer, can You please check out if it's correct?

Answer (score 2):

Suggested by [Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49478/anthony) , subquery has to be replaced with code below:

```
  EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM eshop_productCombinations 
  WHERE eshop_productCombinations.recomended = 1
  AND product-id = eshop_products.id )
```

Comment: Fyi, newer versions of MySQL will try to automatically transform, when possible, `IN` clauses to `EXISTS` clauses, but it's not always a simple transformation that the server can easily and safely apply, which is why it's good to understand *why* certain SQL query designs are more taxing and design queries with this understanding in mind.

Comment: And also, I'm not sure a group by is what you want in that subquery. You don't have any aggregate functions that need them, and the `EXISTS` function probably doesn't benefit as much as you're thinking having the subquery results be distinct.

Comment: Got it, also, this is just a part of old CMS (which is based on older technologies and desparately needs to rebuild in near future) so this will definitely come in handy in near future. Thank you.

Comment: But yeah, you're on the right track. Glad I could point you in the right direction